# MissingMethodException: Method not found

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, indexer

Just not able to understand why I am getting this error. I have code and trying to implement indexer:

```
public class BOCollection<TKey, TValue>
{
    IDictionary<TKey, TValue> _privateDictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
    public TValue this[TKey key]
   {
        get{return _privateDictionary[key];}
        set{_privateDictionary[key] = value;}
    }

//Dictionary Methods
//Other methods
}
```

There is no compile time error, but getting run time error:

> Method not found: 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 NGC.BO.Base.BOBaseClass.get_Child()'.

[image]

Comment: This is often a deployment issue. Check to see whether there is more version of assembly in your bin directory, and better still, clean the bin directory and deploy from fresh. This happens e.g. if you've recently renamed an assembly.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but run time error is still there...

Comment: The code you've posted seems to have no relevance to the error/stacktrace you've given.

Comment: This happened to me this week as well. I have done the following:
Shut down Visual Studio
Delete bin-directory for your application
Delete obj-directory for your application
Delete Temporary ASP.Net Files for your application under C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\
(change Framework if you are running in a 32-bit environment)

I still had issues after this. Then I deleted ComponentModelCache under c:\user\{yourusername}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0
Then I was able to run locally, and now deploying remote. 
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So another solution to this could be, because I experienced this.
I have a project depending on a few other projects. The main project also had reference to one of the other projects - how ever - it did not use it.

So when I deleted the reference in the main object, the problem disappeared. 
I have a feeling the reason is that the main object is built last and therefor it overwrites the newly built otherproject.dll with it's own otherproject.dll ... because it is not being used.

So my suggestion is:
Go over your references and check if it is being used in the project or not. If it isn't - remove it all together.

Answer (score 1):

Your indexer is fine. Seems that your collection have some object(s) that are missing required implementation of `Child` property.